# How can I execute a function only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, increment

For example I have a function

```
Question.prototype.checkAnswer = function(answer1, answer2) {
   if (answer1.innerHTML  == this.correctAnswer) {
    console.log("correct");
    players1.moveCharacter = true;
    pointAmount+= 1;
    point.innerHTML = pointAmount;
  } else {
    console.log("nope")
  }
}
```

it the answer is correct id adds 1 point to the total amount of points. But the problem is that if I do not move to the next question in array and just keep clicking the answer button, I keep getting points for as much as I want before I decide to move on to the next question. How could I fix this so that only once I can answer the question and get only one point for it. I believe somehow I need to make sure that the function is ran only once?

This is probably can be solved pretty easily but I'm new and can't think of anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple flag, and set it to `true` once the function was called.

```js
function Question() {}

Question.prototype.checkAnswer = function(answer1, answer2) {
   
  if(this.answerChecked)
    return; // If answer was already checked, leave.
  
  this.answerChecked = true;
 
  // The rest of your code
  console.log('Run');
}

const question = new Question();

question.checkAnswer('yes', 'no');
question.checkAnswer('again', 'no'); // This will do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check whether `pointAmount > 0` before awarding any more points.

Comment: I believe `pointAmount` is an accumulation of points overtime.